# Aplicacion control horario es necesario homologar?

Tags: aplicación-web

En los ultimos 2 años e desarollado una app con php mysql y javascript multi plataformas en formato app web progresiva, para control de empleados, control horario, geolocalizacion.

Tiene que ser homologada? tiene que pasar por algun proceso de verificación por estado? es legar instalarla en una empresa y que lo use?

Gracias por vuestro tiempo

NO HAGO PUBLICIDAD NO PONGO NOMBRES Y TAMPOCO PAGINAS WEB O ALGO: ES SOLO UNA PREGUNTA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te refieres a España, no. El Real Decreto solo obliga a las empresas a llevar el registro de la jornada laboral. Por ahora no dice nada acerca del método ni el medio (como si quieres utilizar una hoja de Excel). Tampoco dice que deba almacenarse la información de geolocalización. Yo creo más bien que deberías adaptar el software con lo establecido por el Reglamento General de Protección de Datos (RGPD).

Comment: esta parte de RGPD esta cumpliendo todo , solo que tenia miedo que tengo que pasar alguna inspeccion pra poder ser legal este software

Comment: @diaconu liviu, ilegal no será, no te preocupes. También debo decir que también depende de si el uso es interno o bien si es para comercializar a otras empresas.

Comment: la app es un app web prograsiva multi plataforma. y es multi empresas. me e dedicado 2 años de mi vida a crear este app en el tiempo libre. Me gustaria comercializarla .